# Laravel Form::open issue with url()

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to make this work:

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => 'url('/user')', 'class' => 'class2', 'method' => 'GET']) !!}
```

But I'm having errors, I get that the code was expecting a proper close ")"

Then I tried `'url("/user")'` but it says:

> Action App\Http\Controllers\url("/user") not defined

Of course if I do `dd(url('/user'))` works correctly

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: `'action' => 'url('/user')'` looks like misplaced apostrophes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `url` instead of `action`:

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => url('/user'), 'class' => 'class2', 'method' => 'GET']) !!}
```

You should use `action` only for actions, like:

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => 'HomeController@index', 'class' => 'class2', 'method' => 'GET']) !!}
```

https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.4/html#opening-a-form

Comment: completely right, it has solved my problem, thank you very much :)